# Programtically list all completions for some text in powershell

Tags: powershell, process, autocomplete

I am looking for an equivalent to bash's `complete` function where I list all the possible completions for a some text. Basically give me all the options I would get if I repeatedly hit tab. I know there are fancy things out there like powertab, but I need a way to get them as part of a function.

What I am trying to accomplish is to enable tab completion in a inferior process running a dumb shell. The normal tab completion is not available because I am sending and receiving from stdin/stdout. I would like to have a function I can call that will give me all the completions for some text, because otherwise I have nothing to go off of.

Answer (score 1):

As well all know, all OS, languages, script tools have their strengths and weaknesses.

There should be no expectation that what you are used to or want will be in the next thingy you use. If X or Y is not there, then that means you need a 3rdP add-on or you have to write it yourself.

You can config the PowerShell consolehost and ISE for many things, all else requires writing your own code. Learn the keyboard shortcuts for the [PowerShell consolehost, the ISE](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20shortcuts&form=ANNTH1&refig=c0d189956cab4af89238c5c5f83d12cc&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20shortcuts&sc=8-20&qs=n&sk=&cvid=c0d189956cab4af89238c5c5f83d12cc) and [for VSCode](https://www.bing.com/search?q=vscode%20%20shortcuts&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=vscode%20shortcuts&sc=8-16&sk=&cvid=D30C86549E9F4FE4A4995B99D390264E).

There is no 'complete' switch, cmdlet, etc., in PowerShell. To get what you seem to be after in the PowerShell consolehost, you type the cmdlet name, a space, then the dash, then press CRTL+Spacebar.

```
Get-ChildItem -[CRTL+Spacebar]
```

In the editor pane in the ISE and VSCode, there is dynamic popup IntelliSense. 
In the consoles of the ISE and VSCode, the same keyboard combo works.

As far as this use case...

> 'What I am trying to accomplish is to enable tab completion in a
>   inferior process running a dumb shell. The normal tab completion is
>   not available because I am sending and receiving from stdin/stdout. I
>   would like to have a function I can call that will give me all the
>   completions for some text, because otherwise, I have nothing to go off
>   of.'

... you are going to have to code this yourself, using PowerShell's available language features, for example:

- [Argument Completer](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20argument%20completer&form=ANSPH1&refig=794e2966e798477fb479daa135a903f4&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20argument%20completer&sc=3-29&qs=n&sk=&cvid=794e2966e798477fb479daa135a903f4)
- [Dynamic Argument Completion](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20dynamics%20argument%20compltion&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20dynamics%20argument%20compltion&sc=0-38&sk=&cvid=8D9C0A45EF854A0989A4E3513A23EBC1)
- [Dynamic Parameters](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20Dynamic%20Parameters&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20dynamic%20parameters&sc=4-29&sk=&cvid=0B3344D6D031434FBC01EB0D4A0AF514)

Or using a module addon that exists in the MS PowershellGalery.com

```
Find-Module -Name '*expansion*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
Find-Module -Name '*completer*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
Find-Module -Name '*tab*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

See the videos here:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/trevor-powershell/Authoring-Custom-PowerShell-Intellisense-with-Trevor-Sullivan

There are other items, depending on what version of PowerShell you are using, that you can achieve other Bash-like stuff. For Example:

> [How to make PowerShell tab completion work like Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash) New versions
>   of PowerShell include PSReadline, which can be used to do this:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete
```

> To make it permanent, put this command into

```
C:\Users\[User]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1.
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. All of these solutions show how to provide completions to intelisense. I am really looking for the mechanism intelisense uses to obtain that list of completions. Though as you said, just because a unix shell has this feature does not mean that powershell will. My guess is the the intelisense code is buried deep in the proprietary code and normal users cannot see or access it.

Comment: IntelliSense for any application or service on Windows is coded into / embedded by the developer of the code. IntelliSense is not part of the operating system. All such implementations are using the same things as noted above. Example: if you did this [System. then ctrl+spacebar, while in the PowerShell ISE/PowerShellConsolehost/ VSCode, etc, you'd get tab completion/IntelliSense. If you did that same thing in cmd.exe, you'd get nothing, because cmd.exe has no idea what that is, further proving that it's not the OS, or some deep code doing this, but the tool/app/cmdlet.

Comment: Even not all cmdlets provide complete IntelliSense, as shown in the video I point you to in my answer. The video author shows how to add it, using the same pointers I give you above.

Comment: You mentioned some “deep code doing this”. That code is what I was hoping to find. For example windows terminal does not understand ctrl-space when running powershell. It seems like only certain applications get access to it.

Comment: Nope, no deep secret to this. PowerShell has been OSS for a few years now, and if you go to the repo https://github.com/powershell/powershell to view the source code, you will see how enums, parameters, parameter validation, dynamic parameter validation, C/C++/C# classes are in the code provide this. The [System. thing I point to in PowerShell ability to see all the .Net libraries, thus show intelliSense becasue of it. Again, the author of a tool or app has to code this. It is not automatic at any level.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the explanation. I was hoping this would just be a matter of finding the right cmdlet, but it looks more involved then that. At least this answers the question I wanted to ask.